# Attach or Hook an event of all components

Tags: delphi, events, hook

I have a small problem.
I need to create a component that captures some events of a particular type of component independent counsel of their quantity.
Example: I need every time it is called the event TIBDatabase the active component (Palette Interbase) before my component that runs the event code activate automatically configure some properties of the component.
Is to do this automatically? Example: At the time I place the component on the form he make that connection to the events automatically??
Thank you very much.

Note: I could not reproduce the examples of ([How can I dynamically inject code into event handlers in Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441672/how-can-i-dynamically-inject-code-into-event-handlers-in-delphi))

**Edited:**

I'm trying to use the example of "Ritsaert Hornstra". The example of the accepted answer I would have to scan all the components.

The example only works when I activate event component that I want to monitor.
Example: "TIBQuery" component has the "AfterOpen" event when I reproduce the example of the link does not work. However if I put anything in that event in the component instance runs.
He is not doing automatically.
I'm using Delphi XE3.

**Edited 2:**

Hi Craig Young.
Today I have several systems in active production.
What I want to do is implement the security log that was not done at the time that the systems were developed.
It would be the 13th labor of Hercules to do it manually in all of them.
What I need to do.
A component that when adiconado in a Data Module hook / attach some events of the components of the InterBase database.
I just need a working example for me to do the rest. I just want to know who did when it was done and what was done Variables System: g_s_user, g_s_date, g_s_sql.
As almost all components are connected to TDataset my intention to do this and implentação this component.

I do not have a code ready because I still do not know how to do this!

Thank you.

Comment: Since the accepted answer to the link you provided works perfectly and your answer looks like a duplicate of the question. You might  show what you have tried and what did not work.

Comment: What exactly did you try? Also, take look at `TApplicationEvents` implementation.

Comment: These kinds of super-generic, auto-magical, silver-bullet **pseudo** solutions are exactly what gets you into serious trouble creating horribly complex, very rigid and yet _fragile_ systems. I suggest you rather define specifically what you are trying to achieve, and come up with specific solution to a specific problem. E.g. You might define your own component to use instead of the standard IB components. You might create your components at run-time using a factory; ensuring they're correctly configured from the start. The most appropriate solution depends on the **specifics** of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an event handler programaticaly in Delphi is not that hard. For instance, let´s say that you want to add an event handler to respond to the `BeforeDelete` event. You do it like this:

```
interface

type
  TMyDatasetHook = class
  protected
    TargetDataset: TDataset;
    PreviousBeforeDelete: TDataSetNotifyEvent;
    procedure DatasetBeforeDelete(aSender: TObject);
    procedure CleanupHooks(aDataset: TDataset);
    procedure SetupHooks(aDataset: TDataset);
  public
    constructor Create(aDataset: TDataset);
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end; 

implementation

constructor TMyDatasetHook.Create(aDataset: TDataset);
begin
  TargetDataset := aDataset;
  SetupHooks(TargetDataset);
end;

destructor TMyDatasetHook.Destroy;
begin
  CleanUpDataset(TargetDataset);
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyDatasetHook.DatasetBeforeDelete(aSender: TObject);
begin
  // Here goes your code to handler BeforeDelete
  if Assigned(PreviousBeforeDelete) then
    PreviousBeforeDelete(aSender); // Here we call the existing handler
end;

procedure TMyDatasetHook.CleanupHooks(aDataset: TDataset);
begin
  aDataset.BeforeDelete := PreviousBeforeDelete;
end;

procedure TMyDatasetHook.SetupHooks(aDataset: TDataset);
begin
  PreviousBeforeDelete := aDataset.BeforeDelete; // Here we save the existing handler
  aDataset.BeforeDelete := DatasetBeforeDelete;
end;
```

What you need to do now is to instantiate that class passing the target dataset to its constructor

```
 var
   myDatasetHook: TMyDatasetHook;
 begin
   myDatasetHook := TMyDatasetHook.Create(someTargetDataset);
 end;
```

What you need now is to adapt the class above to meet your particular needs.

Answer (score 0):

AlexSC

Dude thanks for the reply.
I've actually solved the problem. It was not pretty. but it worked.
Glad to know that there are people like you willing to help and make constructive comments. Unlike our noble friend Craig. In addition to not helping my question became negative.
If I came to stackoverflow's because I'm really struggling to do. Imagine explaining what I want. But that's okay. I am very grateful to everyone who somehow helped me solve my problem.
In respect to you AlexSC I will post what I did do:
PS: I will take the liberty to enhance my code with example ok?

```
unit Sample;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, Dialogs, IBDatabase, Data.DB, System.Win.Registry, Winapi.Windows;

type
  TSample = class(TComponent)
  private
    FBanco: TIBDatabase;
    FDataSet: TDataSet;
    L_FBeforeScroll: TDataSetNotifyEvent;
    L_FBeforeRefresh: TDataSetNotifyEvent;
    Procedure OnRefresh(DataSet: TDataSet);
    Procedure OnScroll(DataSet: TDataSet);
    Procedure SetBanco(Value: TIBDatabase);
  public
    { Public declarations }
    constructor Create(AOwner : TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy;override;
  published
    { Published declarations }
    property  Database: TIBDatabase read FBanco write SetBanco;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('DataXML', [TSample]);
end;

constructor TSample.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
end;

destructor TSample.Destroy;
begin
  inherited;
end;

procedure TSample.OnRefresh(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  if Assigned(L_FBeforeRefresh) then
    L_FBeforeRefresh(FDataSet);
end;

procedure TSample.OnScroll(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  if Assigned(L_FBeforeScroll) then
    L_FBeforeScroll(FDataSet);
end;

procedure TSample.SetBanco(Value: TIBDatabase);
begin
  FBanco := Value;
  FDataSet := FBanco.DataSets[0];
  L_FBeforeScroll := FDataSet.BeforeScroll;
  L_FBeforeRefresh := FDataSet.BeforeScroll;
  FDataSet.BeforeScroll:=OnScroll;
  FDataSet.BeforeScroll:=OnRefresh;
end;

end.
```